# Converting std::string into hex, and then storing it in a byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, hex

This question probably has an easy answer. I believe I have some working code, but I feel like there is a much better solution.

In any case, this is the problem I'm having:

Basically a user enters some data into a terminal, and my program is monitoring the terminal. It's important to know that I'm not using `cin`, which I know can easily be manipulated to interpret incoming data as hexadecimal. Instead, my program is using an adapted version of conios.h for linux and using `kbhit()`. All user input is stored as a `std::string` until the user decides to submit it.

At that point, I have to interpret the string as hexadecimal - but there's a minor caveat. I have to save this string in a character array.

That said, this is what I have:

```
     ...
     char bufferBytes[6144];
     std::string bufferString = "";
     ...

     for(i = 0; i < bufferString.length(); i = i+2)
     {
        bufferBytes[i] = (stoi(bufferString.at(i), 0, 16) << 4);
        bufferBytes[i] = (stoi(bufferString.at(i+1), 0, 16);    
     }
```

I believe this will do the trick, but I feel like there's probably a better solution.

Any input would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Say a user enters `0123456789ABCDEF`. This is stored as a std::string until the user decides to submit it. At this point, I need to interpret this std::string as hexadecimal numbers and store them in a character array. I believe the code I have above will work, but is there a better/more efficient way of doing what I described.

Comment: Where yo you get `6144` and why aren´t you checking if this is enough for your `bufferString`? And whats the problem?

Comment: It's an arbitrary buffer size (1024 * 6). This isn't an end user program...it's a test script for a UART hardware device I'm interacting with, and I know for a fact any input will never have more than 6000 bytes. I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Your current code writes to `bufferBytes[i]` twice, overwriting the first value.  I believe the second instance should be `bufferBytes[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough snippet that would probably do the job.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < bufferString.length(); i += 2) {

    bufferBytes[i/2] = (bufferString[i] - '0') << 4;
    bufferBytes[i/2] |= bufferString[i+1] - '0';

  }
```

If your intention is to store each hex digit as their own char element then this should be the body of the loop:

```
    bufferBytes[i] = (bufferString[i] - '0') << 4;
    bufferBytes[i+1] = bufferString[i+1] - '0';
```

Comment: Note the `- '0'`, `|=` and the `[i/2]` part.